# Woocommerce product loop - show all product variation-images

Tags: wordpress, loops, woocommerce

In the wordpress front-page.php theme file i loop through all the woocoommerce products and show the featured-image.

```
            <ul class="products">
                <?php

                // Setup your custom query
                $args = array( 'post_type' => 'product' );
                $loop = new WP_Query( $args );

                while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
                    <li>
                        <a href="<?php echo get_permalink( $loop->post->ID ) ?>">
                            <?php the_post_thumbnail( ); ?>
                        </a>
                    </li>

                <?php endwhile; wp_reset_query(); // Remember to reset ?>
            </ul>
```

Now i have some products which are variable products (different colors). Every color variation has its own image. How can i show all the different variation-images inside this loop? My plan is to create an image-slider with these images.

Answer (score 5):

```
<?php
            $args = array( 'post_type' => 'product' );
            $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
            while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
                $product_s = wc_get_product( $loop->post->ID ); 
                if ($product_s->product_type == 'variable') {
                    $args = array(
                    'post_parent' => $plan->ID,
                    'post_type'   => 'product_variation',
                    'numberposts' => -1,
                    );
                    $variations = $product_s->get_available_variations();
                    echo '<pre>';
                    print_r($variations);
                    // You may get all images from $variations variable using loop
                    echo '</pre>';
                }
            endwhile; wp_reset_query(); // Remember to reset ?>
```

I do not have tested yet. But hopefully it will work.

Comment: It works, i get all the data from the product variations. But how can i now just output the image paths of all variations?

Comment: Added answer below. Please check.

Comment: Linter says "Undefined method 'get_available_variations' ,and nothin is echo-ed.

Answer (score 2):

Use below code to get image urls

For Wc3+

```
foreach ( $variations as $variation ) {
    echo $variation['image']['url'];
}
```

And for old Wc versions

```
foreach ( $variations as $variation ) {
    echo $variation['image_src'];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 $args = array(
        'post_type'      => 'product',
        'posts_per_page' => 10,
    );
    $product_arrray = get_posts($args);
    foreach($product_arrray as $prod)
    {
        $product_id = $prod->ID;
        $product = wc_get_product($product_id);
        $pvariation = $product->get_available_variations();
        echo "<pre>";print_r($pvariation);echo "</pre>";
    }
```